# Create pie chart from php using mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table like below

```
buy_trader    qty
--------------------
abc          48000
xyz          40000
pqr          35000
Others       88000
```

I need to create a pie chart from these values using PHP code. Can someone please help me with this. I need to show the percentages of qty out from the total value in the pie chart.

please help me with this

Comment: what are you using for creating pie chart? like highchart etc?

Answer (score 14):

Use either [Google Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/), [JpGraph](http://jpgraph.net/), or [GraPHPite](http://graphpite.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

You could generate an image of the chart from the command line using sqlchart http://www.sqldashboards.com/sqlchart#example-charts allows generating a pie chart straight from your mysql query like so:

`sqlchart --host dbserver --servertype mysql --user ryan --pass 123abc --chart piechart --execute "select * from tbl"`

In fact this is how it would look:
[image: pie chart of sql data]

Answer (score 1):

Some more "charting" libraries what you can work with: [Chart.Js](http://www.chartjs.org/) [AmCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/javascript-charts/)

And I found an [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/4-best-chart-generation-options-php-components/), too about it.

(Edit: Formating)